# gitlab not cloning ( ssh ) stuck at "Cloning into 'repo'..."

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

Hi Im trying to clone repo from gitlab with ssh. but it stucks at

"Cloning into 'repo'..."

Note :

1. same rsa key works fine when i try to clone from github, so there might not be port block issue (not sure on this assumption)
2. HTTPS cloing works fine from GitLab.
3. tried command- ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@gitlab.com but no response just hangs there
4. Tried command -

**root@352-526:~# ssh -vvv git@gitlab.com**

OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *

debug2: resolving "gitlab.com" port 22

debug2: ssh_connect_direct

debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [2606:4700:90:0:f22e:fbec:5bed:a9b9] port 22.

what am I missing. been stuck here for a while.

Comment: Is it still happening now? Earlier today (3/15/2021) Gitlab had a few issues affecting multiple components including `git` on https and ssh. Their [status page](https://status.gitlab.com/) is all clear now, but the [history](https://status.gitlab.com/pages/history/5b36dc6502d06804c08349f7) shows some issues today.

Comment: thanks for responding! Now its cloning. But its taking a long time like before the cloing starts it takes around 5-7 mins just hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answerring my own question -

It was cloning But it takes around 5-10 mins just to start cloning. Dont know why this is happening. But its cloning